# how to check CD or DVD in DVD-RAM drive in java

Tags: java

I wrote how to detect this drive,but not able to check whether it is a CD or DVD  in DVD-RAM drive in java?

Answer (score 1):

in windows you can use WMI to get any information i need, So can run this script in java program to get relevant information, more information  can be found on Microsoft or just search for "windows management Instrumentation"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can detect that.
At most you might be able to query the operating system for the maximum amount of available space and conclude it must be a DVD if that space is more than the maximum that will fit on a CD (640MB if memory serves).